# Using linux system commands in R to remove special characters

Tags: linux, r, sed

I'm trying to clean files using linux system commands in R

I would like to use a command that removes special characters apart from the file separator (pipe delimited)

In the example below it's the slashes and additional quotation marks that I'm trying to get rid of

```
1234|"PJDG"|"CHOCOLATES"|"CHOCOLATE CAKE"
1256|"GADG"|"CAKE \"HA"|"SPECIAL \"HAPPY CHRISTMAS\""
7657|"ASGD"|"WINE"|"RED WINE"
6777|"DAG"|"FRUIT"|"APPLES/LOOSE"
```

I've used the command below, but it doesn't appear to be removing the characters.

sed 's/\"?//g' input_file.txt > output_file.txt;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file `x.txt` looks like this

```
cat(readLines("x.txt"), sep = "\n")
# 1234|"PJDG"|"CHOCOLATES"|"CHOCOLATE CAKE"
# 1256|"GADG"|"CAKE \"HA"|"SPECIAL \"HAPPY CHRISTMAS\""
# 7657|"ASGD"|"WINE"|"RED WINE"
# 6777|"DAG"|"FRUIT"|"APPLES/LOOSE"
```

Then you can use `sed` in `system()`, like this

```
system("sed -e 's|[\\\"]||g' x.txt")
# 1234|PJDG|CHOCOLATES|CHOCOLATE CAKE
# 1256|GADG|CAKE HA|SPECIAL HAPPY CHRISTMAS
# 7657|ASGD|WINE|RED WINE
# 6777|DAG|FRUIT|APPLES/LOOSE
```

You can write that to file. Or if you want to return an R vector, add `intern = TRUE` to the call

Comment: This is great, exactly what I was after. Thankyou

Comment: Can I ask one other thing, do you know of any documentation to learn more about this - it's obviously very powerful, but I've found it difficult to get some good source

Comment: @SamGilbert - I have a couple of really nice reference manuals here at home.  But I also use http://unix.stackexchange.com to find examples for usage.  The ref manuals don't always  provide good examples I've found.

Comment: One of the manuals I use is [The Linux Essential Reference](http://www.amazon.com/Linux-Essential-Reference-Series/dp/0735708525).  Virtually no examples, but it's basically a dictionary of all important linux commands

Answer (score 2):

R system has own functions for that, not necessary to use system. Look at `sub`, `gsub`. Read your file using `readLines`, edit it by `sub` or `gsub` and then save the resulting structure back to separated file.